# Define URL from a web server on iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, webserver

I am working on an iphone app. now i am messed up with a issue. I want to link a file download path URL with a button, so when user click that button, it downloads file from URL at back. Problem is that URL changes so frequently for which i am thinking of doing such that first it seeks for URL online & then downloads. Can anyone help me with that ? So that i just change URL online anytime behind the back of that button in App. If i make static URL at the back of that button, its not gonna work because client says that URL changes almost every 4 days.

Thanks in advance for help.

Example:

just as 2 days ago, URL was : tv.cinstedac.com/iphone/stream.m3u8

but now URL is tv.cinstedac.com/iphone/stream1.m3u8

All i want is to do such that when a person click on that button it downloads file at url, but what will be solution of changing URL ? So that i change it online & it gets updated on App as well !

Comment: I edited my answer, hope this will help you a bit more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the easyest way is to have a static url to a webserver that will return the proper url i suppose. But your question is not 100% clear as of where this url could be found.

**EDIT**

Your edit confirmed my guess, you will need to have a page that is always at the same adress (for example tv.cinstedac.com/iphone/giveStreamUrl.php). which will give only one line of output:

```
tv.cinstedac.com/iphone/stream1.m3u8
```

you could get this url from a database for example. If you want example code i will need some more info about where you will get this url from (database, txt file, etc).